# Convert from string to textbox object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am trying to convert a string to textbox, but I am getting an error that it cannot convert to integer?!

I have the following code:

```
    Dim curr As String
    curr = "Detail_0107"
    Dim NEWTEXT As TextBox = TryCast(Me.Controls(curr), TextBox)

    NEWTEXT.Text = "test"
```

On the TryCast, I get the following error:
Conversion from string "Detail_0107" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Detail_0107 is a textbox on my form.  Can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you're setting Detail_0107 as a string. If you want to set the text of Detail_0107, all you need to do is the following:

`Detail_0107.Text = "test"`

As you said Detail_0107 is already a textbox on your form, there shoud already be an object for it.

Comment: In my code, the curr string will change.  It won't always be "Detail_0107"

Comment: In that case, Joel's is the most relevant answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `Me.Controls.Find(curr)` instead. Additionally, **every** control has a `.Text` property. It's part of the base `Control` type, and therefore you have no need to cast to TextBox. If you're very sure the `Detail_0107` control does exist in that collection, you can get the code down to just this:

```
Me.Controls.Find("Detail_0107").Text = "test"
```

Comment: With that, I get 'find' is not a member of 'system.web.ui.controlcollection'
If I try FindControl, it says the instance is not set to anything. I know you have to recursively use FindControl, but I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: Ahh... WebForms. Use `.FindControl()` instead of `.Find()`.